# QToolBar: Is there a way to add QAction to a QToolBar in QtDesigner?

Tags: pyqt4, qt-designer

I've a PyQt4 Installed on Python 2.6. I wish to insert actions or widgets into a toolbar in QtDesigner instead of adding them in code, with `addAction` or `addWidget` (as simple as adding actions to a menu in design time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add actions by dragging them to your tool bar from the "Action editor" dock window.  You cannot add widgets to the tool bar in Qt Designer, I'm afraid you'll have to do this from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own widget plugins with new or extended functionalities. 
Just follow the definition rules from the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#writing-qt-designer-plugins) .
I use a lot of custom widgets inside the Qt Designer. 
Once you have figured out, how it works, it becomes a really power full method for your design work flow inside Qt Designer.